# debug output of jenkins workflow plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I go my first steps with the jenkins workflow plugin and its really hard to see any problems with batch calls. If I ran an batch in a "normal" freestyle jenkins job I see all the output that produced from the batch. But with the workflow plugin all the output from the batch calls are hidden.

How can I enable the jenkins workflow plugin to show the output of a batch call?

Answer (score 0):

Well [this test](https://github.com/jenkinsci/durable-task-plugin/blob/a98cd9124145d494a153de130459c88b2acd208a/src/test/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/durabletask/WindowsBatchScriptTest.java#L57) shows that output is expected (of course). Certainly sounds like a bug. Is there a minimal reproducible test case? If so, file it.